# Send post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post

How i can send request like this via rails

```
POST /token/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.admitad.com
Authorization: Basic XXX
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public_data&client_id=XXX
```

based on [admitad api](https://developers.admitad.com/doc/api/auth/auth-client/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the POST request via the command line with a tool like [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html):

```
curl --data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public_data&client_id=XXX" http://api.admitad.com/token
```

If you want to use HTTP basic authorization, add the `-u` option:

```
curl --data-urlencode "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=public_data&client_id=XXX" http://api.admitad.com/token -u "client_id:public_key"
```

Another similar command line tool is [httpie.org](http://httpie.org), which uses a slightly different syntax.